# npm | Falha de dependências na instalação

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, bash, npm

**Meu sistema:**
- Windows 10
- Bash on Ubuntu on Windows

Sou novo na utilização do bash. Instalei o `nodejs`, seguido do `npm` e finalmente `grunt`. Funcionou tudo bem. Utilizei o `grunt` sem problema, mas comecei a ter problemas na utilização do `npm`. Não conseguia instalar nada. Então pesquisei e decidi desinstalar o `npm` através do seguinte modo:

> sudo rm -rf
>   /usr/local/{lib/node{,/.npm,_modules},bin,share/man}/{npm*,node*,man1/node*}
>
> To completely uninstall node + npm is to do the following:
>
> go to /usr/local/lib and delete any node and node_modules go to
>   /usr/local/include and delete any node and node_modules directory if
>   you installed with brew install node, then run brew uninstall node in
>   your terminal check your Home directory for any local or lib or
>   include folders, and delete any node or node_modules from there go to
>   /usr/local/bin and delete any node executable

*retirado de [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x/11178106#11178106).*

Reinstalei o `nodejs`, e correu bem, mas ao instalar o `npm` dá-me o seguinte erro:

```
luisalves@localhost:~$ sudo apt-get install npm
sudo: unable to resolve host localhost
A ler as listas de pacotes... Pronto
A construir árvore de dependências
A ler a informação de estado... Pronto
Alguns pacotes não puderam ser instalados. Isso pode significar que
você solicitou uma situação impossível ou se você está a usar a
distribuição unstable em que alguns pacotes pedidos ainda não foram
criados ou foram movidos do Incoming.
A seguinte informação pode ajudar a resolver a situação:

Os pacotes a seguir têm dependências não satisfeitas:
 npm : Depende: nodejs mas não vai ser instalado
       Depende: node-abbrev (>= 1.0.4) mas não vai ser instalado
       Depende: node-ansi mas não vai ser instalado
       Depende: node-archy mas não vai ser instalado
       Depende: node-block-stream mas não vai ser instalado
       Depende: node-fstream (>= 0.1.22) mas não vai ser instalado
       Depende: node-fstream-ignore mas não vai ser instalado
       Depende: node-github-url-from-git mas não vai ser instalado
       Depende: node-glob (>= 3.1.21) mas não vai ser instalado
       Depende: node-graceful-fs (>= 2.0.0) mas não vai ser instalado
       Depende: node-inherits mas não vai ser instalado
       Depende: node-ini (>= 1.1.0) mas não vai ser instalado
       Depende: node-lockfile mas não vai ser instalado
       Depende: node-lru-cache (>= 2.3.0) mas não vai ser instalado
       Depende: node-minimatch (>= 0.2.11) mas não vai ser instalado
       Depende: node-mkdirp (>= 0.3.3) mas não vai ser instalado
       Depende: node-gyp (>= 0.10.9) mas não vai ser instalado
       Depende: node-nopt (>= 2.1.1) mas não vai ser instalado
       Depende: node-npmlog mas não vai ser instalado
       Depende: node-once mas não vai ser instalado
       Depende: node-osenv mas não vai ser instalado
       Depende: node-read mas não vai ser instalado
       Depende: node-read-package-json (>= 1.1.0) mas não vai ser instalado
       Depende: node-request (>= 2.25.0) mas não vai ser instalado
       Depende: node-retry mas não vai ser instalado
       Depende: node-rimraf (>= 2.2.2) mas não vai ser instalado
       Depende: node-semver (>= 2.1.0) mas não vai ser instalado
       Depende: node-sha mas não vai ser instalado
       Depende: node-slide mas não vai ser instalado
       Depende: node-tar (>= 0.1.18) mas não vai ser instalado
       Depende: node-which mas não vai ser instalado
E: Não foi possível corrigir problemas, você tem pacotes mantidos (hold) estragados.
```

Podem-me indicar como posso corrigir esta situação? Conseguirei ter novamente o npm a funcionar?

Comment: Voce esta executando o bash como admin? [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/user_support#permissions)

Comment: Sim estava. Infelizmente como não encontrei solução reinstalei BoUoW. Mesmo assim obrigado pelo interesse.